# Prevent showing chat history when creating an adhoc group chat in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Let's say we are creating an adhoc group chat with multiple people in Microsoft Teams.

[image]

After the first person is added to the chat Teams loads the chat history. Can I turn this functionality off?

This is because I may be creating the while others are watching and I don't always want them to see the history of my 1-on-1 chat with X.

Answer (score -1):

While creating a Group Chat inside Microsoft Teams, you get following options while adding a new user to that group about the chat history.

1. **Don't include the chat history** : New user won't be able to see the previous
   chat history.
2. **Include history from the past number of days**: It gives the access to new user
   to read the chat history for specified number of days.
3. **Include all chat history**: New user will be able to see all chat history of that
   group since it was created.

[image: Group Chat History]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it's not really about my problem.

Comment: You can [start a new group chat by providing a name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mQRT.png) so that it's treated as a new conversation and [history won't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm8FB.png). Please let us know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Let us know if you still facing issue.